# ISO 27001 2013 version not being updated

Tags: iso27001, standards, iso27002

Is there any reason why an information security standard such as ISO 27001 is not getting updated as Information Security field is constantly changing and also the requirements but its latest version is for 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technology is constantly changing. Processes for the management of technology do not change so quickly. The version previous to 2013 was published in 2005. So there is not a change in cadence.

The ISO 27000 series is made up of a [number of documents](https://www.iso.org/ics/35.030/x/), and some have been updated in 2020 and 2019.

ISO 27001 now has a 2022 version. So the cadence up updates is unchanged.